# xslt-param processing instruction - pass a value from xml document to xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters, transform, param

Im doing a uni assignment and cannot (for the life of me) find any information online about the "xslt-param" xml processing instruction. There is information about "xsl:param" but its not the same thing.

Basically I've got an xml document that I want to transform into html, on the client side. My assignment requires me to use "xslt-param" to send a value to the stylesheet, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="http://blah/assign/pass.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xslt-param name="user_entry" select="superman"?>
<root>
    content
</root>
```

And the stylesheet will receive it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="user_entry"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset = "UTF-8" />

                <title>Assignment</title>
            </head>

            <body bgcolor="orange">

                <H3> RESULT...</H3>

                <p>
                    HOWDY.
                    You entered <xsl:value-of select="$user_entry" />
                </p>

                <!--xsl:apply-templates/-->

            </body>

        </html>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Most of this stuff is working...

I just cannot find any information online (or from my supervisor) about the CORRECT TECHNIQUE for using
"xslt-param"

Its almost like this technique doesn't really exist. Does anyone know anything about it?

Im aware that this approach would probably never be used in the real world. But I gotta do the assignment.

Does anyone know where "xslt-param" is documented / explained via tutorial / officially specified?

Thanks

Comment: How about http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_param.asp ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware the processing instruction `xslt-param` is supported by Mozilla browsers, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSLT/PI_Parameters for the documentation.

I am not sure whether other browsers support that.

So for your example `<?xslt-param name="user_entry" select="superman"?>` I think you either want `<?xslt-param name="user_entry" value="superman"?>` (where you assign the string value `superman`) or you want to use an XPath expression with `select` where `<?xslt-param name="user_entry" select="//superman"?>` would select elements named `superman` in the XML input document or where `<?xslt-param name="user_entry" select="'superman'"?>` would be a different way to assign the string value `superman` to the parameter.

Your original sample `<?xslt-param name="user_entry" select="superman"?>` does not make much sense as it would select an element named `superman` as the root element of the input document; however your input sample has a root element named `root`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the processing instruction `<?xslt-param name="..." select="..."?>` or `value="..."` was only supported by Mozilla in the far past.

But the idea to pass xslt parameters to a stylesheet is still a legitimate use case.

An elegant solution could be like this:

```
<!-- Document.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xslt-param name="my_name" value="Sherlock"?>
<?xml-stylesheet ype="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<data> ... </data>


<!-- Stylesheet.xsl -->
<xsl:param name="my_name">
    <xsl:variable name="tmp" select="processing-instruction('xslt-param')[starts-with(., 'name=&quot;my_name&quot;')]"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($tmp, 'value=&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
</xsl:param>
```

Here we use the xslt function `processing-instruction(...)` to match all processing instruction nodes named 'xslt-param' and then filter out those, containing the attribute `name="my_name"`.

Finally extract the actual value using the built-in functions `substring-before(...)` and `substring-after(...)`.

**Solution works in all enviromnents**.

Tested with HTML5-compatible browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) as well as with common XSLT Engines (XALAN, MSXML)